# Path to tex file in different folder

Tags: links, paths

Hi I am doing a presentations, and to all of them I use the same tex file with document settings. I'd like to have one folder on desktop with file with settings, and in each presentation a path to this tex file. Is it possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: just place your settings in some file such as `mysettings.sty` and place it in a directory in the tex INTPUTPATH (eg `~/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage/mysettings.sty`  and use `\usepackage{mysettings}` in your documents

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wouldn't a `texhash` be required?

Comment: @Niranjan no, not by default. The default settings don't restrict `~/texmf` to `lsR` hashed seach.

Comment: How can I make a .sty file?